# OAuth and Angular 17: error "location is not defined" in AuthService.shouldHandleCallback during bootstrap

Tags: angular, oauth, server-side-rendering, angular17

So here is the issue I have been struggling with.

I try to integrate OAuth in and STANDALONE Angular app (Angular 17).

Yet when I declare the provider using provideAuth0 I get an error 500 "location is not defined" from "AuthService.shouldHandleCallback". I have been having a hard time finding working examples that use provideAuth0, all the article I found still use NgModules.

- Angular 17, Standalone, SSR is ON, using @auth0/auth0-angular

in app.config.ts:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(),provideAuth0(env.auth as AuthConfig)] };
```

The config:

```
export const env = {
    production:false,
    server:"http://localhost:3000",
    auth: {
        domain: "dev-hf1ppmebd5jwzhr0.eu.auth0.com",
        clientId: "0a8vBFL18wUsW4PlHVBFXelbQxKYTUtj",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200"
    }
}
```

The error: "location is not defined"

> at AuthService.shouldHandleCallback
> (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@auth0/auth0-angular/fesm2020/auth0-auth0-angular.mjs:504:15)
> at AuthService (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@auth0/auth0-angular/fesm2020/auth0-auth0-angular.mjs:337:10)
> at Object.AuthService_Factory (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@auth0/auth0-angular/fesm2020/auth0-auth0-angular.mjs:511:10)
> at eval (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5239:43)
> at runInInjectorProfilerContext (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3644:9)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5238:17)
> at R3Injector.get (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:5106:33)
> at ChainedInjector.get (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:16452:36)
> at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6711:39)
> at getOrCreateInjectable (e:/projects/dressup/angular/dressup/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6759:12

I went to check the shouldHandleCallback function and it do call "location" in auth0-auth0-angular.mjs:

```
shouldHandleCallback() {
        return of(location.search).pipe(map((search) => {
            const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
            return ((searchParams.has('code') || searchParams.has('error')) &&
                searchParams.has('state') &&
                !this.configFactory.get().skipRedirectCallback);
        }));
    }
```

That doesn't seems to be bound to any config I can pass in, so I am not too sure how to address the issue here. I would appreciate any pointer at what I am doing wrong.

Thanks :)

Comment: It relates to the Angular v15, but the issue seems to be the same, i.e. in SSR you need to mock "empty" Authentication service instead of providing the real one.